# How To Clone/Mutate A Model In Django Without Subclassing

Tags: python, django, django-models, dry, aggregation

'Ello, all. I'm trying to create a model in Django based on - but not subclassing or having a DB relation to - another model. My original model looks something like this: it stores some data with a date/time stamp.

```
class Entry(Model):  
    data1 = FloatField()  
    data2 = FloatField()  
    entered = DateTimeField()
```

I'd also like to aggregate the numeric data for each of these entries on a daily basis, using a model that is almost identical. For the DailyAvg() variant, we'll use a DateField() instead of a DateTimeField(), as there'll only be one average per day:

```
class EntryDailyAvg(Model):  
    data1 = FloatField()  
    data2 = FloatField()  
    entered = DateField()
```

Thus the problem: There's going to be a lot of these data classes that will need a corresponding daily average model stored in the DB, and the definitions are almost identical. I could just re-type a definition for an equivalent DailyAvg() class for each data class, but that seems to violate DRY, and is also a huge pain in the arse. I also can't have EntryDailyAvg subclass Entry, as Django will save a new Entry base every time I save a new EntryDailyAvg.

Is there a way to automaticaly (-magically?) generate the DailyAvg() class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you're not subclassing `Entry` because ... ?

Comment: Actually, I did at one point, and forgot that every time you save the child class, an instance of the parent class gets saved as well. I kept wondering where all the extra Entry()s were coming from - they were being saved every time I saved a DailyAvg(), so all I ended up doing was "polluting" the Entry table.

Answer (score 2):

What if you create a AbstractEntry class with all the data1 stuff and then, two subclasses: Entry and EntryDailyAvg.

Check the docs for info on how to tell django that one class is abstract.

Comment: Abstract classes are new to 1.1, aren't they? Hadn't thought of that. Thanks!